# What's the best way of implementing a 'popular content' display?

Tags: web-applications, statistics

How do I show a list of 'most popular (articles|posts|whatever) for a period such as the past day? (Essentially replicate the functionality of the [Radioactivity](http://drupal.org/project/radioactivity) Drupal module.)

Comment: I guess the solution involves checking how many times each (article|post|whatever) was fetched and sort the results according to this count.  You need to store a counter in the database and increment the view count each time the object is fetched.  You can probably make a generic application out of this.

Answer (score 5):

Here's what I would do:

1. If you're not already, sign up for [Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/) and add the google analytics javascript to each of your pages. This will track view count for you.
2. Using the [google data API library](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-python-client/), fetch the information you want. For example, you could ask for the most popular pages on your site in the last day.
3. Once you have a script that fetches the data you're interested in, you can use [django-celery](https://github.com/ask/django-celery) to schedule a [periodic task](http://ask.github.com/celery/userguide/periodic-tasks.html) (e.g. once an hour, once a day) to run your script and cache the output in your database for display on your site.

Comment: This is a very good suggestion, I never thought about using Google Analytics for this kind of operation. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could decide which posts are popular based on the number of comments on those posts

Answer (score 0):

http://popularposts.benguild.com/ ... that's why I built this. It just receives data from Google Analytics scheduled emails and reminds you to extend them before they stop working after a year.