# Display Google Analytics popular post

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, google-analytics

I want to display "*Popular Post*" on my site using Google Analytics.  I found [past post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7546152/whats-the-best-way-of-implementing-a-popular-content-display) mentioning the same thing but I am not a programmer.  If you know any friendly tutorial how to implement this I would like some recommendations. By the way, I use jQuery for my site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid I know only the programming solution to this. Since you mentioned keywords PHP, here is my solution

```
      <?php
           require 'gapi.class.php';
           $gaEmail = 'youremail@email.com'; 
          $gaPassword = 'your password';
          $profileId = 'your profile id'; //8-digit number 

          $dimensions = array('pagePath','country', 'region', 'city'); 
          $metrics = array('visits');
          $sortMetric=null;
          $filter=null;
          $startDate='2011-02-01';
          $endDate='2011-02-28';
          $startIndex=1;
          $maxResults=10000;

         $ga = new gapi($gaEmail, $gaPassword);

      $ga->requestReportData($profileId, $dimensions, $metrics, $sortMetric, $filter,          $startDate, $endDate, $startIndex, $maxResults);

       $totalPageviews = $ga->getPageviews();

      foreach ($ga->getResults() as $result) {
          $visits = $result->getVists();
          print $visits; 
       }
      ?>
```

Put your particular page's name in the filters to check for the page in which you are looking for the popular post. For example `$filter="pagePath=='popularPost.php"` With this you will get `$visits` with which you can measure the popularity of that post or page.

Keep in mind to turn off your 2-step verification for the google account. If you don't , it will throw you a bad request error despite the validity of your account info.

This is fairly simple since it allows you to fetch all GA information through the back end and embed it in your website. With JavaScript/jQuery you will need to have a client authorization such as a OAuth or AuthSub which requires them to authenticate with your account.

So I recommend this.

Comment: I would not recommend this method for a web app. Client login is a security issue and [Google only recommends it for locally hosted apps](http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/docs/auth/clientlogin.html). A better method would be [OAuth2 with a refresh token](http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/OAuth2InstalledApp.html#refresh). `It is discouraged for web applications to use ClientLogin as their authentication method.` Google supplies [client libraries for many languages including PHP](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/wiki/OAuth2) for the OAuth2 method.